# nodejs twitter api in docker container throw 401 error

Tags: node.js, docker, twitter, dockerfile

I am working on a nodejs twitter api and it's working perfectly fine in the local env but when I try to containerize, it fails with a 401 error from twitter.js which is "HTTP 401 Unauthorized client error status response code".

Error

```
> node app.js

Error: Status Code: 401
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/twitter/lib/twitter.js:277:28)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.onRequestResponse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1059:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:603:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:472:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
```

I did my search on this where I found that this could a time mismatch issue in the docker container. My docker container is running 1 and a half hours behind the actual time. I am not sure if this is the only issue.

My docker file

```
FROM node:13.13.0-alpine
    
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ENV KAFKA_HOST=localhost:9092 \
    KAFKA_TOPIC=tweetstream 

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

How can I set the right time in this docker image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on a Windows host machine and as I mentioned in the question there was a time difference between my host and the containers.

What I did to resolve the time difference?

```
Search Hyper-V Manager -> Docker Desktop VM (seen on right bottom) -> Settings (new popup will open)
```

```
Management -> Integration services -> Time Synchronization (uncheck) -> Apply -> ok
```

```
Again go to the same location and check the Time Synchronization -> Apply -> ok
```

I also feel you will have to redo it once your windows machine goes into hibernation.

Reference articles: https://thorsten-hans.com/docker-on-windows-fix-time-synchronization-issue

https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2015/10/31/time-in-docker-containers/

Answer (score 0):

OAuth requires close time synchronisation, so that is very likely to be the issue, especially if your code works outside of the container in a system where the time is synchronised.